# How to parse class with arrays of properties to json

Tags: python, json

I got a class with arrays of classes as properties

```
class classToJson():

    def __init__(self, name, image, objects1, objects2):
        self.name = name
        self.image = image
        self.boolean = True
        self.objects1 = objects1
        self.objects2 = objects2

    def __repr__(self):
        return json.dumps(self.__dict__)
```

object1 and object2 class looks like this:

```
class object1():
    value1 = 1
    value2 = 0

class objects2:
    def __init__(self, name, value):
        self.name = name
        self.value = value
```

This is how I create my json of the class.

```
obj2 = [...]
parsedObject = classToJson(name, image, [object1], obj2)
file = open("{}.json".format(name),"w")
file.write("[{}]".format(parsedObject.__repr__()))
file.close()
```

This works if I only use `name, image` and `boolean` in the class but when I include `objects1` or `objects2` I get the `TypeError: Object of type 'type' is not JSON serializable`. Why?

The json schema I want to accomplish:

```
[
  {
    "name": "name",
    "image": "image",
    "boolean": true,
    "objects1": [
      {
        "value1": 1,
        "value2": 0
      }
    ],
    "objetcs2": [
      {
        "name": "name",
        "value": "value"
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use the built in `json.dump` like so

```
import json
with open('file.json') as f:
    json.dump([{
        'name': name,
        'image': image,
        'boolean": True,
        'object1': object1,
        'object2': object2
    }], f)
```

Comment: Not really what I asked for but your solution is much prettier.